# 'protocol failure' when attempting 'cordova run android' (APUS)

Tags: android, cordova, adb

When attempting `cordova run android` I am getting:

> ERROR: Failed to launch application on device: ERROR: Failed to
>   install apk to device: Error executing "< ... >": protocol failure

This did not happen previously.
Recently APUS was installed on my Android phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling APUS on my android fixed this.

(Settings > Apps > (APUS) > Uninstall)
and then restarting my phone.